# How do I stop a div taking up space?

Tags: html, css

I am doing stuff with ajax progress bars and stuff...

Basically I have a hidden div that says "Loading" in it, and beneath it I have a visible div with my content in.

When it is loading, it fades the content div out, makes the hidden div visible, and moves it via javascript/relative positioning to be in the middle of the content.

It looks quite badass but unfortunately when the div is made visible, even though its relatively positioned, it takes up a line so my content moves down.

Do you know how I can stop it from taking up space when it is made visible?

Edit: Someone removed the tag it seems

The loading div starts off display none, so it takes up no space, and then when it is made visible, it starts taking up space, even though it is positioned relatively.

I could use visible and non-visible, but then it would force my content window down all of the time.

It looks like absolute positioning is the way to go.

What I want to do is combine absolute and relative positioning. I am trying to get the absolute coordinates of the content div and setting its location that way, but without success yet.

Edit: I just re-read your answer and you have done exactly that. Thank you!

Comment: it has nothing to do with 'asp.net': could you remove the tag?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> "Do you know how I can stop it from taking up space when it is made visible?"

Position it absolutely.

```
div#theParent {
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:640px;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
div#theChild {
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:400px; 
  top:50px;
  left:120px;
}

<div id="theParent">
  <div id="theChild">
    <p>This div is absolutely positioned to a relatively-positioned parent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote. He asked how to keep a relatively-positioned item from shifting siblings when it is visible.

Comment: +1 from me - unless I'm misreading the question, yours is the only answer that answers his question (which is about how to stop it moving things when made visible, not how to stop it taking up space when invisible).

Comment: if you play with absolute position, of course the div will not move... But even if the question was asked in that way, the good practice is to use the 'display:none' instead of the 'visible:hidden'... That is why I vote down.

Comment: let's him try both solutions and he will choose the correct 'as-he-wants' answer.

Comment: I think this is right but I am not sure how to implement it to get an absolutely positioned item, positioned relative to the parent...

Comment: SLC, you must set the parent to position:relative, so that the absolute coordinates are based on the parents position in the document. Look at my example again.

Comment: Figured it out, thank you very very much. Some people are so wise, but this site is teaching me such a huge amount.

Comment: SLC: Good work! Wisdom comes with time. You'll soon be the guy with all the answers ;) Just remember to come back and share your wisdom when you can :)

Comment: @enguerran: actually display:none / visibility:hidden pose an accessibility problem with screen readers (as they don't offer javascript more often than not), the recommandation is therefore to move elements out of the screen with ridiculous absolute positions (-999em for example)

Comment: absolute behave weird with safari

Answer (score 5):

When you want to make it invisible, make it really invisible with `style="display:none"`.  There are many ways to do this...not sure how you have this set up or how you're altering your dom elements.  Provide some more context (doing this with Ajax controls, custom JavaScript, a library like jQuery, etc), and we can give you a more specific solution.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but now that we have `position:sticky;` and want to play nice with it, one way to do it is to set `height:0; overflow:visible;`

Comment: "height:0; overflow:visible;" works beautifully for temporal progress bars and error messages under the inputs if you want your margins to be consistent across various screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to play with the *display* option, not the *visible* option :

> Tip: Even invisible elements takes up space on the page. Use the "display" property to create invisible elements that do not take up space!

see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp)

**[EDIT]**

After reading [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/#trouble), even if they do not collected any mistake about [pr_class_visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp), they do about [pr_class_display](http://w3fools.com/#pr_class_display): so
[never see w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp)

But you can see [reference.sitepoint.com](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility) :

> Descendant boxes of a hidden box will be visible if their visibility is set to visible, whereas descendants of an element for which display is set to none can never generate boxes of their own.

Answer (score 2):

You can try various things, like. Depends on how your code is constructed. Since you didn't provide an example :)

```
display: none;
height:0px 
line-height: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this has been answered, but if you are using bootstrap try:

```
class='hide'
```

instead of

```
class='hidden'
```